# Copy Multiple Lines to variable in python using pyperclip

Tags: python, pyperclip

The code i wrote just create a structure and print it in multiple lines
How can create a string to contain all the Lines

```
import pyperclip
symbol = input('Symbol = ')
width = int(input('Width = '))
height = int(input('Height = '))

while height > 0:
 print(symbol * width)
 height = height - 1

print('\nCopy to Clipboard ?\nY For Yes\nN For No\n')
sel = input('')
if sel == 'Y':
 pyperclip.copy('Here i want to copy the Structure')
elif sel == 'N':
 print('Done')
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? As it stands, it's not very coherent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use f-string and addition.

```py
results = ""
while height > 0:
    results += f"{symbol * width}\n"
    height - = 1

print(results)
```

This should produce the same output as you code, but this time you have a unique string.

Comment: Thanks it worked But i didn't understand it i will search for unique strings

Comment: @alsaibi You can addition two string, two produce a final one. Is what the script do and that replace the `join` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to build up the strings and then use them all at once

```py
import pyperclip
symbol = input('Symbol = ')
width = int(input('Width = '))
height = int(input('Height = '))

structure = '\n'.join([symbol * width for x in range(height)])

print('\nCopy to Clipboard ?\nY For Yes\nN For No\n')
sel = input('')
if sel == 'Y':
    pyperclip.copy(structure)
elif sel == 'N':
    print('Done')
```